# Skype Room System - Add a Local USB Button to share the local Content

Tags: powershell, usb, skype

On Skype Room System which the installation is based on PowerShell, there is no possibilty to share a content from a local USB stick. There is only the possibility to share the content of devices connected to the meeting.

Does someone have modified (Through PowerShell) the current GUI of Skype Room System to add this button called "Local USB content"?

Thanks for your support.

Regards,

Alain

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft explicitly forbids that because they deem USB as an enterprise security threat. I'd suggest you check out SRS alternatives like [Flipdock](https://www.flipdock.com), it does everything SRS does and much more when it comes to content - you can open, share, and annotate content from a USB drive, cloud drive, websites, calendar invite attachment, and much more.

If you'd like a demo, visit flipdock.com/contact and mention my name in the message.